# What does an Area Description File (ADF) looks like?

Tags: google-project-tango

I'm starting to work with the Google Tango Tablet, hopefully to create (basic) 2D / 3D maps from scanned areas. But first I would like to read as much about the Tango (sensors / API) as I can, in order to create a plan to be as time efficient as possible.

I instantly noticed the ability to learn areas, which is a very interesting concept, nevertheless I couldn't find anything about these so called Area Description Files (ADF).

I know the ADF files can be geographically referenced, that they contain metadata and an unique UUID. Furthermore I know their basic functionalities, but that's about it.

In some parts of the modules ADF files are referred to as 'maps', in other parts they are just called 'descriptions'.

So what do these files look like? Are they already basic (GRID) (2D) maps, or are they just descriptions?
I know there are people who already extracted the ADF files, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Tango ADF Doco](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/overview/area-learning)

> Important: Saved area descriptions do not directly record images or
>   video of the location, but rather contain descriptions of images of
>   the environment in a very compressed form. While those descriptions
>   can’t be directly viewed as images, it is in principle possible to
>   write an algorithm that can reconstruct a viewable image. Therefore,
>   you must ask the user for permission before saving any of their
>   learned areas to the cloud or sharing areas between users to protect
>   the user's privacy, just as you would treat images and video.

Other than that there doesn't seem to be much info about the file internals -  I use a lot of them, but I've never been compelled to look inside - curious yes, but not compelled

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've seen that part on the Tango Docs, and it made me more curious. Is it possible for you to send me one of your ADF files?

Comment: Soon -  right now my ADFs are in my house or places I've gotten specific permission for - I now have people who have granted me public access for the next set of milestones and those ADFs will be available -  that said, unless you're where they were recorded they won't do you much good, save in the attempt to reverse engineer the file format.  And that might make Google frown, but it's your call.   And if this answer helped, could you mark it answered ?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without any direct info from the project Tango folks anything we provide would be merely speculation.  I'm with Mark, not much compelling reason to get details.  My speculation: probably contains a set of image descriptors, like SIFT, and whatever other known device settings are available, like GPS location, orientation (gravity), time(?), etc.

Comment: Each image descriptor must also be associated with its 3D location in the area frame of reference. "Loading" an area probably consist in placing all the descriptors in a data structure optimized for spatial location like an octree.

Answer (score 0):

I got the ADF file, basically **coded binaries** and seems difficult to decode.

I will be happy to share the file if anyone is still interested.

Comment: Google released an official ADF file inspector, so check this [link](https://developers.google.com/tango/tools/adf-inspector), it may be helpful if you are still looking for ADF file information.